# GWT: form in FlexTable cell

Tags: gwt, file-upload, datepicker

I need to place a FormPanel in the FlexTable cell. A Form conteins one DateBox and one FileUpload field and must be displayed by click on the cell.  When a form contained in the cell, datepicker don't able to set picked value in the field as well as FileUpload don't set path to the file picked in file upload dialog. But datepicker popup and file upload dialog displayed properly. 
I'm trying to set focus on fields like this:

```
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        public void execute () {
            dbox.setFocus(true);
        }
    });
```

but it result in DateBox make a displayed already with opend datepicker popup.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved for DateBox, but remained the same for FileUpload. Is there analog of setFocus method of DateBox class for FileUpload?